# Batch move files in folders to newly created folders

Tags: batch-file, directory, move, subdirectory

I want to move all files in some folders to a newly created folder in that same folder. For easier understanding, see the example below (the input is shown left, output is shown right):

```
C:\1\A\file1.tif            C:\1\A\Named\file1.tif
       file2.tif                         file2.tif
       file3.tif     ==>                 file3.tif
C:\1\B\file1.tif            C:\1\B\Named\file1.tif
       file2.tif                         file2.tif
       file3.tif                         file3.tif
```

In the example above, I have only shown the first three files in every folder, but the total number may vary (usually there are 1000 files per folder). Also, I have only shown two folders (A and B), but the total number of folders may vary as well (usually about 10 folders). Finally, I have only shown the folder '1', but the number of these kind of folders may also vary (usually '1' through '10'). So I was looking to a script that could do these actions independent of the number of files or folders, and independent of the names of the folders/files (I chose '1', 'A' and 'file1.tif' only as examples).

The idea is that, now, I have to manually create empty folders (called 'Named' in the example above) in each folder ('A' and 'B' in the example above) where the files are. Then I have to manually move all the files into that newly created folder 'Named'. I have to do this for all folders (about 100). I can do this entire process manually if I had to do it only once, but the thing is that I have to do this process many times :-). So automating this would save a lot of time.

Does anyone know a script that can do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough testing, this works great. However, as it is a lot of files, you may want to set up a little test environment, like in your example, to use this on first, before you use it on your actual data.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd C:\rootfolder
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a:d') do (
attrib "%%a\*.*" | find "File not found"
if !errorlevel!==1 (
if not exist "%%a\Named" md "%%a\Named"
xcopy "%%a\*.*" "%%a\Named"
del "%%a\*.*" /f /q
)
)
```

Comment: Hi Bali, thank you for the script. I tested the script by changing the first line to "cd C:\1". This works perfectly. But as I mentioned in my first post, the '1' folder is not the only one, there are usually 10 folders (so 1 through 10). When I replace the first line in the script by "cd C:\" (assumed that there are no other folders in the C drive other than the folders 1 through 10) the script still works, but I get additional empty folders called 'Named' in the '1' folder (so C:\1\Named). Same goes for the 9 folders ('2' through '10'). But it's not a big problem.

Comment: @Loek No worries, I put the rootfolder path as a kind of placeholder for a folder with all of your folders in (like your example of using C: with no other folders) so unless you have some sort of root folder it's hard to distinguish the ones you want from the ones you don't if you know what I mean. I did actually find that problem myself when I was testing but I thought I had fixed it, I will do some more debugging :)

Comment: I just tested my script but it seems to work fine for me. I just created a folder `test` and underneath had 2 folders, `a` and `b`, each with 2 text files and it worked fine. Would it be possible for you to create a base folder and move everything into there and see if it works?

Comment: I mean when there's one more folder level. So for example when `C:\Base\ ` is my root folder. Then I have `C:\Base\1\A\file1.tif` but also `C:\Base\2\A\file1.tif` . When I replace the first line of the script by `cd C:\Base` I get additional empty folders like `C:\Base\1\Named\ ` and `C:\Base\2\Named\ `. I hope it's clear. Also, when I look to your code it mentions some 'copy' commands. Wouldn't it be more efficient to use 'move' commands instead? If it's much more difficult to implement 'move' commands, it's no problem, I can also wait for the files to be copied instead of moved :-).

Comment: Ah right, I see what you mean, so you want to just create a Named folder if there are files to move into it? I initially used `move` but the problem is `move` also moves folders, so when you try and move everything into Named, it moves Named itself, into another Named, so you get a blank duplicated Named folder, so `xcopy` and `del` is a good workaround.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Only create a Named folder when there are files to move into it. But if that's too difficult I'm sure I can find some scripts that only delete empty folders (the empty 'Named' folders in this case).

Comment: It shouldn't be, I will do some scripting now and see what I can come up with :)

Comment: I have updated my answer, it will only create the folder and move the files if files are present in the folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working brilliantly now! This is really going to save some time :-). Thanks again.

Comment: I tried the script on the real data and it's working perfectly. But it takes too long to process all the files. Is it possible to use the `move` command instead of the `copy` command? I understand that it will create additional empty 'Named' folders as you explained, but that's not really a problem compared to the long processing time.

Comment: Or you could use `robocopy` like @rene has. With the `mov` and `create` switches, but I'm not sure what that's like speed wise, have a play and see what works best.

Comment: I replaced `xcopy` by `move` and removed the `del "%%a\*.*" /f /q` line. It's about 20 times faster now and I don't get any additional empty 'Named' folders :-). Thanks!

Comment: Great stuff, I must have been doing it wrong to get the extra ones :)

Answer (score 1):

tested a little, this might work, in a command file

make a cmd file with these lines

```
for /r %%a in (*.*) do  call :singlecopy %%a
goto :eof

:singlecopy
set src=%~p1
set dst=%~p1NAMED
set file=%~n1%~x1
rem replace NAMED in src with nothing
set srctst=%src:NAMED=%
rem if src and srctst are still the same, copy 
if %srctst%==%src%  robocopy %src%  %dst% %file% /move /create
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the code in CMD (Admin) but it didn't work. I got the following result (only showed the first iteration): pastebin.com/3VtnWpPE http://puu.sh/1Hdh0

Comment: fixed source destination and file options

Comment: I tried the new script, and it did something. But not the right thing. I ended up with the files in this location: C:\1\NAMED\NAMED\NAMED\NAMED\NAMED\NAMED\NAMED\...\NAMED\NAMED\NAMED\NAMED\file1.tif etc.(in total 42 NAMED folders). See also this screenshot: http://puu.sh/1HBBQ.png Same for C:\2\NAMED\NAMED\...

Comment: That is unfortunate, sorry. I've create a batch file that should do a better job...

Comment: Thanks for the new script. I tested the script by placing the script in the C:\1\ folder and run it (by double clicking it). But unfortunately all it seems to do is create a folder C:\1\NAMED\. In that folder comes the .bat file (but the .bat is empty when I open it with Notepad). Anyway, thanks for all your efforts!